# Huawei 5C - locked out wanting PIN1

Tags: sim-card, locked-out

I have a rooted Huawei 5c that I'm locked out of. It requires 'SIM1 - PIN1' which AFSAK I never created. Normally one gets three attempts and then you have to input PUK (which I have); that I'm aware of. The thing is, it's not responding to 'three attempts', it just does nothing after numerous attempts.

[image]

A bit of background.

This whole issue began when I put a PAYG SIM in the second SIM slot. When I booted back up, it required 'SIM1 - PIN1' for the phone to start, which I don't have. I removed the second SIM and booted into the phone as normal. Went to the security section and this is where potentially the mistake was made. I thought the phone was asking me to enter (read: create) the password for the SIM card, but nope... it already had a default password and was asking me to enter that. I entered (read: tried to create) a password twice, and BAM... now locked out of the phone, whichever SIM is present or both. As I mentioned it is not responding to three attempts.

I have access to ADB and the command line, is there anything I can do with that? Any help appreciated.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/138086/discussion-on-question-by-cliff-huawei-5c-locked-out-wanting-pin1).

Answer (score 0):

Something went wrong and the data are damaged. Here are some steps to follow, try each one:

1. Try default PIN codes: 0000, 1234, 1111, etc
2. Reboot into the recovery then clear the phone cache. Either with adb command `adb reboot recovery` or by key combo.
3. Perform a factory reset from the recovery.
4. Flash the device with a fresh ROM.
   You can get the firmware and the flashing guide from [Huawei Support site](http://consumer.huawei.com/in/support/mobile-phones/honor5c-in-sup.htm). Unzip the zip and follow te instructions.